# nginx rewrite do nothing

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

i have created a little CMS with PHP and MySQL.
Now i try to activate NGINX rewrite but it do not work and i can not understand why?

(Example) I have a Page

http://www.example.com/cars.php?id=bmw

I tries to use this Rule

rewrite ^/listings/(.*)$ /listing.html?listing=$1 last;

From: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

But it does not work.

rewrite ^/cars/(.*)$ /cars.php?id=$1 last;

I get the same ugly URL http://www.example.com/cars.php?id=bmw

Should I change the URL anchor in the PHP document?
From

```
<a href="cars.php?id='.$row['name'].'"> BWM </a>
```

to

```
<a href="cars/'.$row['name'].'"> BWM </a>
```

when I do it works.
But when I click from BMW side on contact page I get this strange URL

```
http://www.example.com/cars/contact
```

Has anyone an idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your document you are specifying URIs without a leading slash. This means that they are considered to be relative to the current page.

You want to use pretty URIs (like: `/cars/bmw`), which is fine, except that it contains an embedded `/` which looks like a directory path. This *directory path* is used to construct URIs which do not contain a leading `/`.

The solution is to provide all of your URIs with a leading `/`, which will avoid any ambiguity.

For example:

```
<a href="/cars/'.$row['name'].'"> BWM </a>
<a href="/contact"> Contact Page </a>
```